# How to connect to SIP server with DNS domain

Tags: ios, dns, sip, voip, pjsip

I'm developing VOIP application in iOS, for that I'm using PjSip library. I'm successfully connecting and making and getting calls with normal IP or domain address, which means a single server. When I'm trying to connect with DNS(Domain Name system) as of now using two servers, I'm facing some errors. Can any one help me to resolve this problem and provide me some sample code how to connect to DNS.
Here is my code what ever I tried

```
 char dns = "sample.com";
 while (anObject = [enumerator nextObject])
 {
   NSMutableString *mutableStr = [anObject mutableCopy];
   CFStringTrimWhitespace((CFMutableStringRef)mutableStr);
   srv = [mutableStr UTF8String];
   if (srv && strlen(srv))
   {

      if (app_config->cfg.nameserver_count==PJ_ARRAY_SIZE(app_config->cfg.nameserver))
      {
         PJ_LOG(1,(THIS_FILE, "Error: too many DNS servers"));
         [mutableStr release];
         break;
      }
      for (i=0; i<app_config->cfg.nameserver_count; ++i) {
          pj_ansi_sprintf(line, "--nameserver %.*s\n",(int)app_config->cfg.nameserver[i].slen,app_config->cfg.nameserver[i].ptr);
      }
      pj_strdup2_with_null(app_config->pool, &(app_config->cfg.nameserver[app_config->cfg.nameserver_count++]), srv);
  }
  [mutableStr release];
}

/* Initialize pjsua */
status = pjsua_init(&app_config->cfg, &app_config->log_cfg, &app_config->media_cfg);
uname  = "2000";
authname  = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"authname"] UTF8String];
passwd = "abcdef";
sipServer = "sample.com";
pjsua_acc_config_default(&acc_cfg);
acc_cfg.use_rfc5626 = PJ_FALSE;
// ID
acc_cfg.id.ptr = (char*) pj_pool_alloc(/*app_config.*/pool, PJSIP_MAX_URL_SIZE);
if (contactname && strlen(contactname))
  acc_cfg.id.slen = pj_ansi_snprintf(acc_cfg.id.ptr, PJSIP_MAX_URL_SIZE, 
                                   "\"%s\"<sip:%s@%s>", contactname, uname, sipServer);
else
  acc_cfg.id.slen = pj_ansi_snprintf(acc_cfg.id.ptr, PJSIP_MAX_URL_SIZE, 
                                   "sip:%s@%s;transport=tcp;hide", uname, sipServer);
if ((status = pjsua_verify_sip_url(acc_cfg.id.ptr)) != 0) 
{
   PJ_LOG(1,(THIS_FILE, "Error: invalid SIP URL '%s' in local id argument", 
  acc_cfg.id));
  return status;
}
acc_cfg.reg_uri.ptr = (char*) pj_pool_alloc(/*app_config.*/pool,
PJSIP_MAX_URL_SIZE);
acc_cfg.reg_uri.slen = pj_ansi_snprintf(acc_cfg.reg_uri.ptr, 
PJSIP_MAX_URL_SIZE, "sip:%s;transport=tcp;hide", sipServer);
if ((status = pjsua_verify_sip_url(acc_cfg.reg_uri.ptr)) != 0) 
{
   PJ_LOG(1,(THIS_FILE,  "Error: invalid SIP URL '%s' in registrar argument",
  acc_cfg.reg_uri));
   return status;
}

acc_cfg.cred_count = 1;
acc_cfg.cred_info[0].scheme = pj_str("Digest");
acc_cfg.cred_info[0].realm = pj_str("*");//pj_str(realm);
if (authname && strlen(authname))
  acc_cfg.cred_info[0].username = pj_str((char *)authname);
else
  acc_cfg.cred_info[0].username = pj_str((char *)uname);
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"enableMJ"])
   acc_cfg.cred_info[0].data_type = PJSIP_CRED_DATA_DIGEST;
else
  acc_cfg.cred_info[0].data_type = PJSIP_CRED_DATA_PLAIN_PASSWD;
acc_cfg.cred_info[0].data = pj_str((char *)passwd);
acc_cfg.publish_enabled = PJ_TRUE;
#if defined(MWI) && MWI==1
  acc_cfg.mwi_enabled = PJ_TRUE;
#endif
acc_cfg.allow_contact_rewrite = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"enableNat"];
acc_cfg.reg_retry_interval = 300;
acc_cfg.reg_timeout = 3600;
if (acc_cfg.reg_timeout < 1 || acc_cfg.reg_timeout > 3600)
{
   PJ_LOG(1,(THIS_FILE, "Error: invalid value for timeout (expecting 1-3600)"));
   return PJ_EINVAL;
}
acc_cfg.ka_interval = 40;
status = pjsua_acc_add(&acc_cfg, PJ_TRUE, acc_id);
```

Here is the response what I'm getting in my console.

```
2016-07-28 10:12:29.899 MYApp[266:39854] granted
2016-07-28 10:12:29.904 MYApp[266:39854] -[Reachability isReachableViaWiFi] (632)
Reachability Flags: -R -------
10:12:31.842 os_core_unix.c !pjlib 2.3 for POSIX initialized
10:12:31.848 sip_endpoint.c  .Creating endpoint instance...
10:12:31.851          pjlib  .select() I/O Queue created (0x17a75f34)
10:12:31.852 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-msg-print" registered
10:12:31.852 sip_transport.  .Transport manager created.
10:12:31.852   pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: NULL --> CREATED
2016-07-28 10:12:31.856 MYApp[266:39854] RESOLVED 0:<192.168.0.1>
2016-07-28 10:12:31.856 MYApp[266:39854] RESOLVED 1:<192.168.0.2>
10:12:37.822 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-log" registered
10:12:37.826   pjsua_core.c  .Nameserver sample.com added
10:12:37.826 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-tsx-layer" registered
10:12:37.826 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-stateful-util" registered
10:12:37.826 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-ua" registered
10:12:37.826 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-100rel" registered
10:12:37.826 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua" registered
10:12:37.827 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-invite" registered
10:12:37.871 coreaudio_dev.  .. dev_id 0: iPhone IO device  (in=1, out=1) 8000Hz
10:12:37.871 coreaudio_dev.  ..core audio initialized
10:12:37.871          pjlib  ..select() I/O Queue created (0x17a79214)
10:12:37.901 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-evsub" registered
10:12:37.901 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-presence" registered
10:12:37.901 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-mwi" registered
10:12:37.901 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-refer" registered
10:12:37.901 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-pres" registered
10:12:37.901 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-im" registered
10:12:37.901 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-options" registered
10:12:37.901   pjsua_core.c  .1 SIP worker threads created
10:12:37.901   pjsua_core.c  .pjsua version 2.3 for  initialized
10:12:37.901   pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: CREATED --> INIT
10:12:37.903   pjsua_core.c  SIP UDP socket reachable at 192.168.1.55:5060
10:12:37.903  udp0x17a80200  SIP UDP transport started, published address is 192.168.1.55:5060
10:12:37.904    tcplis:5060  SIP TCP listener ready for incoming connections at 192.168.1.55:5060
10:12:37.904   tcplis:49851  SIP TCP listener ready for incoming connections at fe80::186d:af8f:4693:2b3d:49851
10:12:37.905   pjsua_core.c  SIP UDP socket reachable at fe80::186d:af8f:4693:2b3d:50425
10:12:37.905 udpv60x1824be0  SIP UDP IPv6 transport started, published address is [fe80::186d:af8f:4693:2b3d]:50425
10:12:37.905   pjsua_core.c  PJSUA state changed: INIT --> STARTING
10:12:37.905 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-unsolicited-mwi" registered
10:12:37.905   pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: STARTING --> RUNNING
2016-07-28 10:12:43.307 MYApp[266:39854] There IS internet connection
10:12:43.308    pjsua_acc.c  Adding account: id=sip:2000@sample.com;transport=tcp;hide
10:12:43.308    pjsua_acc.c  .Account sip:2000@sample.com;transport=tcp;hide added with id 0
10:12:43.308    pjsua_acc.c  .Acc 0: setting registration..
10:12:43.308    pjsua_acc.c  ..Warning: cannot use source TCP/TLS socket address for Contact when nameserver is configured.
10:12:43.309    pjsua_acc.c  ..Warning: cannot use source TCP/TLS socket address for Contact when nameserver is configured.
10:12:43.309     resolver.c  ...Transmitting 38 bytes to NS 0 (192.168.0.1:53): DNS SRV query for _sip._tcp.sample.com: Success
10:12:43.309    pjsua_acc.c  ..Acc 0: Registration sent
10:12:45.311     resolver.c !Re-transmitting 38 bytes to NS 0 (192.168.0.1:53): DNS SRV query for _sip._tcp.sample.com: Success
10:12:47.311     resolver.c  Re-transmitting 38 bytes to NS 0 (192.168.0.1:53): DNS SRV query for _sip._tcp.sample.com: Success
10:12:49.311     resolver.c  Re-transmitting 38 bytes to NS 0 (192.168.0.1:53): DNS SRV query for _sip._tcp.sample.com: Success
10:12:51.313     resolver.c  Re-transmitting 38 bytes to NS 0 (192.168.0.1:53): DNS SRV query for _sip._tcp.sample.com: Success
10:12:53.313 _sip._tcp.samp  DNS SRV resolution failed for _sip._tcp.sample.com: Operation timed out (PJ_ETIMEDOUT)
10:12:53.313 _sip._tcp.samp  DNS SRV resolution failed for _sip._tcp.sample.com, trying resolving A record for vabsys.com
10:12:53.314     resolver.c  Transmitting 28 bytes to NS 0 (192.168.0.1:53): DNS A query for vabsys.com: Success
10:12:55.314     resolver.c  Re-transmitting 28 bytes to NS 0 (192.168.0.1:53): DNS A query for vabsys.com: Success
10:12:57.315     resolver.c  Error transmitting request: No working DNS nameserver (PJLIB_UTIL_EDNSNOWORKINGNS)
10:12:57.315 _sip._tcp.samp  DNS A record resolution failed: Operation timed out (PJ_ETIMEDOUT)
10:12:57.315  sip_resolve.c  DNS A record resolution failed: Operation timed out (PJ_ETIMEDOUT)
10:12:57.315  tsx0x17a87664  Failed to send Request msg REGISTER/cseq=27562 (tdta0x18252000)! err=70009 (Operation timed out (PJ_ETIMEDOUT))
10:12:57.315    pjsua_acc.c  ..SIP registration failed, status=503 (Operation timed out (PJ_ETIMEDOUT))
10:12:57.315    pjsua_acc.c  ..Scheduling re-registration retry for acc 0 in 0 seconds..
2016-07-28 10:12:57.316 MYApp[266:39945] Status changed acc 0 Service Unavailable (503)
10:12:57.318    pjsua_acc.c !Deleting account 0..
10:12:57.319    pjsua_acc.c  .Account id 0 deleted
10:12:57.319   pjsua_core.c  Shutting down, flags=0...
10:12:57.319   pjsua_core.c  PJSUA state changed: RUNNING --> CLOSING
10:12:57.325   pjsua_call.c  .Hangup all calls..
10:12:57.325  pjsua_media.c  .Call 0: deinitializing media..
10:12:57.325  pjsua_media.c  .Call 1: deinitializing media..
10:12:57.325  pjsua_media.c  .Call 2: deinitializing media..
10:12:57.325  pjsua_media.c  .Call 3: deinitializing media..
10:12:57.325   pjsua_pres.c  .Shutting down presence..
10:12:58.326   pjsua_core.c  .Destroying...
10:12:58.326  pjsua_media.c  .Shutting down media..
10:12:58.440 sip_transactio  .Stopping transaction layer module
10:12:58.440 sip_transactio  .Stopped transaction layer module
10:12:58.440 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-unsolicited-mwi" unregistered
10:12:58.440 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-options" unregistered
10:12:58.440 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-im" unregistered
10:12:58.440 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-pres" unregistered
10:12:58.440 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua" unregistered
10:12:58.440 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-stateful-util" unregistered
10:12:58.440 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-refer" unregistered
10:12:58.440 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-mwi" unregistered
10:12:58.440 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-presence" unregistered
10:12:58.441 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-evsub" unregistered
10:12:58.441 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-invite" unregistered
10:12:58.441 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-100rel" unregistered
10:12:58.441 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-ua" unregistered
10:12:58.441 sip_transactio  .Transaction layer module destroyed
10:12:58.441 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-tsx-layer" unregistered
10:12:58.441 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-msg-print" unregistered
10:12:58.441 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-log" unregistered
10:12:58.444    tcplis:5060  .SIP TCP listener destroyed

10:12:58.445   tcplis:49851  .SIP TCP listener destroyed


10:12:58.445 sip_endpoint.c  .Endpoint 0x17a75864 destroyed


10:12:58.445   pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: CLOSING --> NULL



10:12:58.445   pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA destroyed...
```

Please Help me how to connect with the DNS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed, the above code working and connecting to the name server. The issue was with server side only. Now both sides working good. Thanks for your valuable time guys.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. What was the actual problem?

Comment: I don't know what was the problem at server side, I thought they changed their configurations at their side. Now it working with out changing the above code.

Answer (score 1):

If I take a look at your logs, pjsip cannot resolve the dns because it cannot get a resolved ip address from the nameserver located at 52.86.229.130. Maybe you can try an add another nameserver in the configuration?

Comment: I had a talk with my network people, There was a issue at there side only. Now its working fine. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

1) Although it seems fine but please make sure you have #define PJSIP_HAS_RESOLVER   1 in your complile time flag.
  2) As Bob Specified it cannot get a resolved ip address from the nameserver located at 52.86.229.130
  3) Your nameserver (52.86.229.130) is responding but response from server is blocked by router or in between network.

So answer may vary on your network connectivity.

Comment: I had a talk with my network people, There was a issue at there side only. Now its working fine. Thanks for your response.